# How to check if string has / character at the end in C program

Tags: c, string, path, comparison, strcmp

I am writing a simple C program

```
char *path;
```

I want to check if path has trailing `"/"` at the end, I tried `strcmp` function but its giving me segmentation fault.

```
if (strcmp(path[strlen(path)-1], "/") == 0)
```

How can I check if string has `"/"` at the end

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

since a string in c is an array of characters you just need to check the last character before the \0

instead of strcmp use something like this

```
const int len = strlen(path);
if ( len > 0 && path[len-1] == '/' )
{ 

}
```

Comment: you can get rid of `int len = strlen(path);` by using strlen straight into the if condition

Comment: that is correct, but normally one would probably need the value again inside the if statement to e.g. remove the '/' and i find it more clear to use a variable. the optimizer will anyway remove any unnecessary code.

Comment: This will barf on empty strings.

Comment: @rubenvb well i updated the question to satisfy your attention to detail.

Comment: Great! +1 from me `:)`

Comment: I usually go for the belt-and-suspenders approach and add an `if (path)` around it as well, and initializing path itself to n`null`. But that's only because I don't trust myself.

Comment: @sukhvir normally an optimizing compiler would handle that.

Answer (score 1):

By using `path[strlen(path-1)]`, you're passing a single char to `strcmp`, which is not allowed, because `strcmp` expects a null-terminated character sequence.

Instead, compare it directly:

```
if (path[strlen(path)-1] == '/') { ... }
```